# Оконные функции и GROUP BY в одном запросе

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle

Есть следующий код:

```
SELECT PT."date", 
       MAX(COUNT(PT.TRIP_NO)) OVER () MAXC
  FROM PASS_IN_TRIP PT
    JOIN TRIP T ON T.TRIP_NO = PT.TRIP_NO
  WHERE T.TOWN_FROM = 'Rostov'
  GROUP BY PT."date"
```

Он работает корректно, считается максимум среди всех рейсов по дням (по сути, все строки будут одинаковы в этом столбце).

При этом другой код:

```
SELECT PT.DATE, 
       MAX(COUNT(PT.TRIP_NO) OVER (PARTITION BY PT.DATE)) MAXC
  FROM PASS_IN_TRIP PT
    JOIN TRIP T ON T.TRIP_NO = PT.TRIP_NO
  WHERE T.TOWN_FROM = 'Rostov'
  GROUP BY PT.DATE
```

Работать отказывается, заявляя ошибку:

> (30483) ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here

Прошу объяснить принцип взаимодействия агрегированных и оконных функций. Если я правильно понял, оконная функция может браться от агрегированной функции, но не наоборот.

Догадка: причина в том, что оконная берется в самом конце, после применения группировки и фильтрации по `HAVING`. Это так?

Comment: *Догадка: Причина в том, что оконная берется в самом конце, после применения группировки и фильтрации по HAVING?* Именно. Оконная функция применяется к финальному набору.

Comment: С точки зрения корректности синтаксиса записи, скобки в оконной функции правильно стоят? Может так: `MAX(COUNT(PT.TRIP_NO)) OVER (PARTITION BY PT.DATE) MAXC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сказано в главе [Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056):

> Analytic functions are the last set of operations performed in a query except for the final ORDER BY clause. **All joins and all WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses are completed before the analytic functions are processed**. Therefore, analytic functions can appear only in the select list or ORDER BY clause.

Аналитические функции выполняются последними, за исключением финального `ORDER BY`. Поэтому они и могут быть использованны только в листе выборки или `ORDER BY`.

И ошибка вполне объяснима -- **нельзя передать аналитическую функцию как аргумент в агрегированную функцию**, ведь она ещё не может быть подсчитана:

```
~$ oerr ora 30483
```

> 30483, 00000, "window  functions are not allowed here"
>   *Cause: Window functions are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
>            And, **window function cannot be an argument to another window or group
>
>            function**.